# Is there a way to get the path to the tensorflow lite model in an android app?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I wanted this to use in the createFromFileAndOptions method in the ImageClassifier class.

Answer (score -1):

For android applications, it is common to copy the .tflite model file to the assets directory of the Android module where the model will be run. Also it needs to specify that the file should not be compressed, and add the TensorFlow Lite library to the module’s build.gradle file:

```
android {
    // Other settings

    // Specify tflite file should not be compressed for the app apk
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

}
```